# How to set rtsp connection timeout in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg library to write to the rtsp stream.
It is working well when the rtsp url is correct.
But when this rtsp url is incorrect then it is stuck in avformat_write_header.
Is there any solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to following link:
[[FFmpeg-user] How do I set a timeout for an RTSP source?](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-June/022086.html)

> There are two timeout type of options for RTSP:
>
> ‘-timeout’
>
> ```
> Set maximum timeout (in seconds) to wait for incoming connections.
>
> A value of -1 mean infinite (default). This option implies the
> ‘rtsp_flags’ set to ‘listen’. ‘reorder_queue_size’
>
> Set number of packets to buffer for handling of reordered packets.
> ```
>
> ‘-stimeout’
>
> ```
> Set socket TCP I/O timeout in micro seconds.
> ```

Comment: I think OP is asking about libav API. You might have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: it is trivial to set API options using av_opt_*() on ffmpeg objects such as the AVFormatContext that belongs to the rtsp stream. The name of the option will be identical to the name in the ffmpeg CLI application.

Comment: Refer to the protocol documentation. For live streaming the -reconnect_at_eof was very useful in HTTP scenarios, there are others based on the protocol http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http

Answer (score 1):

Both ‘-timeout’ & ‘-stimeout’ do not work for me.

My solution [python code] is:

```
while True:
    try:
        check_call('ffmpeg -i <rtsp://your-input-stream-url> -frames:v 1 screenshot.jpg', shell=True, timeout=N)   # try to get a screenshot if RTSP stream is OK
    except TimeoutExpired as e:
        logger.error('RTSP stream error')   # send error message if timeout
        break
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents here. Sometimes you are establising the connection and need to close it if there's no stream in N seconds. A simple `-timeout` option will switch your connection mode (may be unwanted) and they had some bug in older versions of ffmpeg that made `-stimeout` fail your purpose sometimes.

Here's *one more* timeout, the [rw_timeout](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#toc-Protocols:%7E:text=the%20following%20options%3A-,rw_timeout,-Maximum%20time%20to):

> rw_timeout
> Maximum time to wait for (network) read/write operations to complete, in microseconds.

As said, it is a network-related option, could be of use both with ffmpeg utils and from source code.